# How can I find where a particular view is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a legacy project that has the following two view files:

```
app/views/devise/registrations/_sign_up.html.erb
app/views/devise/devise/registrations/_sign_up.html.erb
```

I know where the first file is used, but not the second one. How can I find where this view is used?

And if I think it's not used anywhere (which I hope is the case), how can I be 100% sure that I'm right about that?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a `devise` directory inside of the `/devise/` directory. I can tell you from experience that devise does not set applications up this way, and if you are trying to use boiler-plate devise, this directory is useless.

Comment: "Why do you have a devise directory inside of the /devise/ directory." I would love to know! I didn't write the code. The question is where this view is used.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have another devise folder in your devise folder, looks like the previous maintainer copied it accidentally or something. I suggest either moving or deleting the folder and seeing if the app still works by testing all the features related to devise (register, log in, log out). If it does (which it probably will), great!

Comment: This is not a bad suggestion, but it unfortunately doesn't completely answer my question. My question was how can I see where a view is used, and if it doesn't appear to be used anywhere, how can I be sure I'm right about that? Just because removing the file doesn't break what I would *expect* it to break doesn't mean it didn't break *anything*. In legacy projects like this, all assumptions of reasonable/logical design choices must go out the window.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a simple way to determine if a view is used without a doubt. The only other thing you could do is search your entire project for mentions of it, I'd start with `grep "devise/devise" -r .`. In all likelihood, your extra devise folder was an accident, so as long as the app works you can be reasonably sure it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We need some trial and errors if experience can't be 100% guaranteed.

At first, add some stupid error code on that template, say

```
<%= nil = 1 %>
```

Then, since this template is about sign up, go through the sign up related features in app and see if there will be error thrown. If integration tests are available, that would be much better, just run them.

If no error, you'll have more confidence to delete this template.

The bottom line is you have version controlled this file so you can recover it in the future if you really deleted it wrongly.

**Add:** *reply to comment*

There is another method. Check what words/html codes are special and then grep them in `/tmp`. Or if that is a public app, google "special words site:theapp.com". Combining these three methods, if you still can't find it. Delete it! You won't regret!

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion, and might be helpful. But what if `app/views/devise/devise/registrations/_sign_up.html.erb` is used in some crazy place I would never expect? Seems like I would have to manually visit every page (since the app doesn't have 100% test coverage) in the app in order to know whether I've loaded that error-throwing `nil = 1` code or not.

Comment: @JasonSwett, yes this is not 100% guaranteed but still better than guess :) I've also added some more methods.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations I usually just `grep` the codebase for any mentions of `sign_up`.  Find them all, rename the file you're curious about to ensure it's unavailable by that name, and then go through its uses one by one to make sure they're not broken.  Best case you can figure it out just by eyeballing the grep results.  I'm pretty sure the nested `devise/devise` directory is an accident and can be removed.